# Changing the pretty-printing of delimiters in a listings language

Tags: symbols, listings, delimiters

In my listings language I have

commentstyle=\color{red}

`morecomment = [n][commentstyle]{(*}{*)}`

So comments are written (* df *) in the tex file and they turn out like

[image: example].

These thick, centred asterisks don't look right for my language. I'd prefer them to turn out like `\text{a*b}` would (where the asterisk is smaller and rises halfway up, exactly as it appears on StackExchange). I need to use asterisks outside of comments as well, and ideally I'd like to choose the style of those separately. I know I can change the style of asterisks by putting them in the literals, but that means my comments don't work. So is it possible to change the style of comment-delimiters (without changing the input of the listings environment), and is it possible to independently change the style of literals which partially overlap with comment-(or other)-delimiters?

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{Isar}{
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    moredelim = [s][stringstyle]{"}{"},
    morecomment = [n][commentstyle]{(*}{*)}, 
    literate=
                {\\<not>}{{$\neg$}}1 
                {\\<times>}{{$×$}}1
  }[comments,strings]%
  
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Isar]{}  
locale Line_Measure = Lines isLine
  "a*b" (*df*) 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```